# Random positon of elements inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Div element on my website which shows the data returned by the ajax response.However the elements that are recieved by the ajax response when shown using this `$('#cakebox').html(content);` where `cakebox` is the Div id gives the output in this straight line fashion.

[image]

The elements that are present in the response are in the form

```
 <img src="ski.png" height="13px" width="15px">
 <img src="ski.png" height="13px" width="15px">
 <img src="ski.png" height="13px" width="15px">
 <img src="ski.png" height="13px" width="15px">
 <img src="ski.png" height="13px" width="15px">
 <img src="cho.png" height="15px" width="15px">
 <img src="cho.png" height="15px" width="15px">
 <img src="ch1o.png" height="15px" width="15px">
 <img src="ch1o.png" height="15px" width="15px">
```

Now what i want to achieve is that instead of positioning them in straight line fashion.Place them anywhere in the Div randomly.Something like the Blue marks present in the image below.So how do i achieve that ?

[image]

**Note:** Ajax call is set on an `on click` event handler when the user hits the button next time these elements might reduce or increase depending on the value that has been put by the user.But the whole flow of data send and recieved remains the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rnayzkrs/5/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, you should give some extra informations about Math.random