# loop through ajax response elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button which makes an ajax call to a php file which in turns sends some html data as a response.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    cherry: cherry,
                    chocolatechip: chocolatechip,
                    butterscotchchip: butterscotch,
                    gems: gems,
                    sweetner: sweetner
                },
                url: 'customcakebox.php',
                success: function (content) {


                }
            });
```

Html Response contains these three elements:

```
<img id="abc1" src="ski.png" height="13px" width="15px">
<img id="abc2" src="cho.png" height="15px" width="15px">
<img id="abc3" src="cho.png" height="15px" width="15px">
```

However these elements can reduce or increase depending on the condition specified in the php file.

What i was wanted to do is to loop through these elements and only print those elements that i want to print?

**Note :** *I know you will say why can't i just pass the ones that i need to  show*.Well , the problem is i want to display every element randomly inside the div and to make that work.I do need every one of them.

[Random positon of elements inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082961/random-positon-of-elements-inside-div) This is what i am trying to achieve.(This is just for reference as to what i am trying to do)

**.php file:**

```
require 'connect.inc.php';
require 'session/inc.encrypt.php';
$cherry = $_REQUEST['cherry'];
$chocolatechip = $_REQUEST['chocolatechip'];
$butterscotchchip = $_REQUEST['butterscotchchip'];
$gems = $_REQUEST['gems'];
$sweetner=$_REQUEST['sweetner'];
$items = '';
if ($cherry > 20)
    $cherry = 20;
else if ($cherry < 0)
    $cherry = 0;
if ($chocolatechip > 20)
    $chocolatechip = 20;
else if ($chocolatechip < 0)
    $chocolatechip = 0;
if ($butterscotchchip > 20)
    $butterscotchchip = 20;
else if ($butterscotchchip < 0)
    $butterscotchchip = 0;
if ($gems > 20)
    $gems = 20;
else if ($gems < 0)
    $gems = 0;

if ((!empty($cherry) || $cherry == 0) && (!empty($chocolatechip) || $chocolatechip == 0) && (!empty($butterscotchchip) || $butterscotchchip == 0) && (!empty($gems) || $gems == 0)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cherry; $i++)
    {

        $items .= ' <img src="ski.png" height="13px" width="15px">';
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $chocolatechip; $i++)
        $items .= ' <img  src="cho.png" height="15px" width="15px">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $butterscotchchip; $i++)
        $items .= '<img  src="che.png" height="15px" width="15px">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $gems; $i++)
        $items .= '<img  src="but.png" height="15px" width="15px">';

}

$customcake['cherry']=$cherry;
$customcake['chocolatechip']=$chocolatechip;
$customcake['butterscotchchip']=$butterscotchchip;
$customcake['gems']=$gems;
$customcake['sweetner']=$sweetner;

$_SESSION['customcake']=$customcake;

echo $items;
```

Ids has not been set here.Please don't  mention that .I will set that later.

Comment: Can you change the .php to return a JSON object that contains the image markup? This way you will have an object that is immediately enumerable. The JSON would look like this: 
{
  "img1": "<img id='abc1' src='ski.png' height='13px' width='15px'>",
  "img2": "<img id='abc2' src='cho.png' height='15px' width='15px'>",
  "img3": "<img id='abc3' src='cho.png' height='15px' width='15px'>"
}

Comment: @ScottMarcus Post an answer with explanation regarding this comment

Comment: You could load the response up into a temporary element as children and then query the temporary object for its child nodes and put then in an array, assign the random order and then re-write them back to the permanent element.

Comment: If you know your tag names and attribute keys will always be the same, you can compact it all into an array, and have javascript build the elements. `[["ski.png",13,15],["cho.png",15,15],["cho.png",15,15]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say the response you returned is in a variable called content, then put this code to run a loop

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(content).filter('img').each(function(index,item) {
    alert(item);
  });
});
```

and in the loop you will get each image as item object. if your response is returning more than image object then you can use $(content).filter('img').each also

Comment: This always thows an error if the response is not of json type

Comment: @scott Hi, Please check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pbv9x1a0/ and you can clearly see its running a loop

Comment: @NahidSuhail Please try my code once, i have even created a jsfiddle for you this will definately work with response type = html

Comment: @ScottMarcus Updated the code, the jsfiddle one just had the variable defined and filter added , which i explained in comment.

Answer (score 1):

If your .php could respond with JSON, something like this:

```
{
  "img1": "<img id='abc1' src='ski.png' height='13px' width='15px'>",
  "img2": "<img id='abc2' src='cho.png' height='15px' width='15px'>",
  "img3": "<img id='abc3' src='cho.png' height='15px' width='15px'>"
}
```

When you receive the results (as your `content` argument to your success callback), you could loop through the response like this:

```
var jContent = JSON.parse(content);

for(var i = 0; i < jContent.length; ++i){

    // whatever you need to do
    console.log(jContent.img1); // <img id='abc1' src='ski.png' height='13px' width='15px'>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an element array in your PHP file and then return it as a JSON object.

```
json_encode( $img_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Then you can make your things with that array at success function. Don't forget to pass an option **dataType**.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    cherry: cherry,
                    chocolatechip: chocolatechip,
                    butterscotchchip: butterscotch,
                    gems: gems,
                    sweetner: sweetner
                },
                url: 'customcakebox.php',
                success: function (content) {


                },
                dataType : "json"

        });
```